# how to remove before and after text in a case where each line is different but has the same separators notepad++

Tags: notepad++

i wanted to try and remove text before and after a separator but the text in the middle isn't all the same example being.

```
123:12313@mail.com:hello
hello:12nj@randomwebsite.com:891
```

and the result I would like.

```
:12313@mail.com:
:12nj@randomwebsite.com:
```

I tried finding a find and replace string on here but I could not find one that met my needs per say. Found and tried using different formats, I tried editing find and replace strings but all didn't work for what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*?(:.+?:).*$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    .*?         # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    (           # group 1
        :           # colon
        .+?         # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
        :           # colon
    )           # end group 1
    .*          # 0 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: If it is just about the colons, this could be another option `^[^\n:]*(:[^\n:]+:).*$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird: You're right but but it's longer to type ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Find and Replace* feature with *Regular Expression* mode.

In your case, the separator is the colon (:) and you want to keep the text between the colons and remove the rest.

Direction:

1. Open the Find and Replace dialog (Ctrl + H).
2. In the "Find what" field, enter the following regular expression: `(.*:)(.*)(:.*)`. This expression will match any text before and after the colon.
3. In the "Replace with" field, enter `\2`. This will replace the matched text with the second group (the text between the colons).
4. Make sure "Regular expression" is selected as the Search Mode.
5. Click "Replace All" to apply the changes.

Expected Output:

```
:12313@mail.com:
:12nj@randomwebsite.com:
```

Comment: You don't need 3 capture groups here, only the middle one would suffice and then replace with `$1` and note that the OP wants to keep the surrounding `:` See your current output here https://regex101.com/r/3MfszS/1